# Fetching Available Times from MySQL with Node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm building a booking app in node.js with MySQL. I have an available-times endpoint, which fetches my entire availability by day of week, and then filters out the appointments that have already been booked. All appointments are in one hour increments. MySQL dates/times are all formatted as TIME.

My endpoint in server.js:

```
`app.get('/available-times', (req, res) => {const { date } = req.query; // Expecting date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' formatif (!date) {return res.status(400).send('Date query parameter is required');}
```

```
// Helper function to convert time strings to Date objects for comparison
const timeStringToComparableDate = (timeString) => {
  const baseDate = new Date(0); // Use epoch time as a base
  const [hours, minutes, seconds] = timeString.split(':').map(Number);
  baseDate.setUTCHours(hours, minutes, seconds);
  return baseDate;
};

const dayOfWeek = new Date(date).getDay(); // JavaScript's getDay() returns 0 (Sunday) - 6 (Saturday)
const sqlAvailabilities = 'SELECT * FROM availability WHERE weekday = ?';

console.log('Day of Week:', dayOfWeek);
db.query(sqlAvailabilities, [dayOfWeek], (err, availabilityResults) => {
  console.log('Availability Results:', availabilityResults);
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }

  const sqlAppointments = 'SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date = ?';
  db.query(sqlAppointments, [date], (err, appointmentResults) => {
    console.log('Appointment Results:', appointmentResults);
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }

    const availableTimes = availabilityResults.filter(avail => {
      // Convert availability times to Date objects for accurate comparison
      const availStartTime = timeStringToComparableDate(avail.start_time);
      const availEndTime = timeStringToComparableDate(avail.end_time);

      // Filter out slots that overlap with booked appointments
      const isBooked = appointmentResults.some(app => {
        const appStartTime = timeStringToComparableDate(app.start_time);
        const appEndTime = timeStringToComparableDate(app.end_time);
        return (appStartTime < availEndTime) && (appEndTime > availStartTime);
      });

      return !isBooked;
    });

    // Map to the desired format for the response
    const formattedTimes = availableTimes.map(slot => ({
      start: slot.start_time,
      end: slot.end_time
    }));

    console.log('Filtered Available Times:', formattedTimes);
    res.json(formattedTimes);
  });
});
});
```

> The console.log results when I access http://localhost:5000/available-times?date=2024-02-19:
> Day of Week: 1

`Availability Results: [
RowDataPacket {
id: 3,
weekday: 1,
start_time: '09:00:00',
end_time: '17:00:00',
created_at: 2024-02-08T02:04:45.000Z

> }
> ]
> Appointment Results: [
> RowDataPacket {
> id: 29,
> student_email: 'student3@example.com',
> date: 2024-02-19T00:00:00.000Z,
> start_time: '13:00:00',
> end_time: '14:00:00',
> created_at: 2024-02-18T09:30:57.000Z,
> firstName: null,
> lastName: null
> }
> ]
> Filtered Available Times: []

I don't understand why it's able to fetch the availability, the appointments, but not filter out the appointments from the availability.

I've been trying to debug by console.logging, and I've included my results above. I'm accessing the endpoint directly instead of trying to use the frontend. I'm stuck on the filtering logic.